# send data to java.js page then send it to another page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a script, on the customers page I have

```
<a href='hueimx.php?action=edit&uid={$result['uid']}'>click to edit</a>
```

and

```
{$result['uid']}
```

This is a customer id that I am getting from a database.

Now I want to receive the "uid" value on my javascript page. This is my code:

```
function insert() {
// Optional: Show a waiting message in the layer with ID login_response
document.getElementById('huemix_message').innerHTML = "<img src='images/saver.gif' />"
// Required: verify that all fileds is not empty. Use encodeURI() to solve some issues about character encoding.
var system_name= encodeURI(document.getElementById('system_name').value);
var system_logo = encodeURI(document.getElementById('system_logo').value);
var system_number = encodeURI(document.getElementById('system_number').value);
var system_tel = encodeURI(document.getElementById('system_tel').value);
if($("#system_pics").is(':checked')){
      var system_pics = 1;
   } else {
      var system_pics = 0;
   }
if($("#system_bread").is(':checked')){
      var system_bread = 1;
   } else {
      var system_bread = 0;
   }

// Set te random number to add to URL request
nocache = Math.random();
// Pass the login variables like URL variable
http.open('get', 'huemixpanel_insert.php?system_name='+system_name+'&system_logo='+system_logo+'&system_number='+system_number+'&system_tel='+system_tel+'&system_pics='+system_pics+'&system_bread='+system_bread+'&uid='+uid+'&nocache = '+nocache);
http.onreadystatechange = insertReply;
http.send(null);
}
```

In this page I recieved all the values from the setting page and forward it to the php page to insert them into the database. Everything is working OK, but I don't know how to receive the "uid" value and send it as you see.

Comment: Not sure if I understand fully, but if you're just trying to track values (like the user id) wouldn't it be easier to use a session variable on the server instead?

Comment: In order to get useful answers here, you have to put some effort in your questions you ask here. 1.) What are you trying todo? 2.) What do you expect. 3.) What happend instead. We are all volteers, so help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If your only objective is to send the data from one page to another page. Then you can easily do this by appending the data in the URL. And on the other page just grab the data and process your operation.

Your script is perfect for sending the data. On the other page "***huemixpanel_insert.php***" you please consider adding this line of code:

```
<?php
if(!empty($_GET['uid']))
{
    $uid = strip_tags($_GET['uid']); // check for security hole
    //Your rest of the  ***huemixpanel_insert.php*** code goes down here...  
} else {
    //You can die the rest of the page if uid is not received. (Optional) don't use else if you don't want to take any action. 
}
?>
```

Comment: ok look
i have a setting page for my script ..
<form action ='javascript:insert()' >

Comment: @user2175697 Have a look to the above solution.. and tell me if you still have problem.